# Koa + XMLHttpRequest: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: node.js, ajax, cors, xmlhttprequest, koa

I have simple koa server deployed on Heroku and use `XMLHttpRequest` for ajax. In my post request I get error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://upload-file-endpoint.herokuapp.com//upload-file' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

**server.js**

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const Router = require('koa-router');
const cors = require('@koa/cors');
const serve = require('koa-static');
const path = require('path');
const koaBodyMultipart = require('koa-body')({ multipart: true });

var corsOptions = {
  origin: '*'
};

const app = new Koa();
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(serve(path.join(process.env.PWD, '/dist')));

const router = new Router();

router
  .post('/upload-file', koaBodyMultipart, (ctx, next) => {
    const { file } = ctx.request.files;
    if (file) {
        ctx.response.body = ctx.request.body;
    } else {
        ctx.throw(500,'Error Message');
    }
  })
  .post('/upload-file-error', koaBodyMultipart, (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.throw(500,'Error Message');
  });

app.use(router.routes()).use(router.allowedMethods());

// don't listen to this port if the app is required from a test script
if (!module.parent) {
  var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 1337);
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('running at port:' + port)
}
```

**ajax post request**

```
var file = fileUpl.getFile();
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", "https://upload-file-endpoint.herokuapp.com//upload-file", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);
xhr.send(formData);
```

I am using [@koa/cors](https://github.com/koajs/cors) library. I tried to initialize `cors` with and without `corsOptions`.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@koa/cors": "^3.0.0",
    "koa": "^2.7.0",
    "koa-body": "^4.1.0",
    "koa-router": "^7.4.0",
    "koa-send": "^5.0.0",
    "koa-static": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1"
  }
```

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? Use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: (Incidentally, you really probably don’t want to be making your application code send back a 500 error. 5xx errors are basically intended for server systems to send back when there’s some internal server failure, right? You probably want to be sending some appropriate 4xx error instead.)

Comment: @sideshowbarker this endpoint is meant to occur when server is not able to process a file because of server a failure. I don't know why, but it works now and I didn't change anything. I think it is because I added `corsOptions`, then deployed on Heroku and tried it out. Maybe I needed to wait a bit after deployment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try it now, it works. Server is deployed on Heroku.

I added

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: '*'
};
```

Probably I didn't wait, when it was deploying on Heroku.